# Delete specific files by extension locally then push Deletes to Remote

Tags: git

I just pushed a bunch of stupid sourcemap files with extension `.map` to my remote repo with a push.

I want to remove those map files and there are a bunch of them.

What's the best way to do this?  I forgot to add .map to my gitignore, well that's there now but now I need to go back and delete the files both locally and in the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a unix-like system (Linux or MacOS), you can use the find command, like so:

```
find . -type f -name "*.map" | xargs git rm
```

This will delete all the map files and stage the deletions for a commit.

You can then go ahead and do a *git commit* and a *git push*.

Comment: tried it then got master ✗                                                                                                                                                                                        7m ⚑  
▶ find . -type f -name "*.map" | xargs git rm
fatal: pathspec './dist/client/lib/ink-3.1.10/js/autoload.min.js.map' did not match any files

Comment: I called the command at the root of my project.  I really need to just target my src folder

Comment: tried this too ▶ find ./src -type f -name "*.map" | xargs git rm
fatal: pathspec './src/test/unit/components/interview/CompanyHeader/interview.company.logo.spec.js.map' did not match any files

Comment: then just change to your src folder

Comment: try just executing the find command, without the xargs and git rm

Comment: worked thanks much! When we gonna list RedGate Patrick on my site :P . Guess who this is :)

Comment: no, that was just for troubleshooting, it doesn't delete anything, it just finds the files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155720/discussion-between-patrick-hund-and-positiveguy).

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: It sounds like that one particular `.js.map` file was an *untracked* file: not in the index, and hence not going to be committed anyway. Git cannot remove it because it is not in the index. (Git has a secret intermediate copy of every file, which Git calls "the index", or sometimes "the staging area" or "the cache". When you run `git commit` Git just saves whatever is in the index—it doesn't even have to look at your work-tree at this point. This is why you have to `git add` constantly: to copy from work-tree into index, to update the stale version sitting in the index.)